# Restore SQL Server 2008 R2 database to SQL Server 2012 and getting syntax errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

My application is working on SQL Server 2008 R2 and I need to move it to SQL Server 2012, so first I restored the database backup on SQL Server 2012 and then set compatibility level to 100, but RAISEERROR syntax errors are showing up which are related to triggers. There are so many triggers in the database, do I have to amend each and every trigger manually or what should be its best approach?

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

Comment: "Best approach"? Correct EVERY instance of raiserror to match the syntax change. Then run the upgrade advisor to find any other things that need to be addressed. In additio, why bother upgrading to an already old version of sql server? Far better to use 2016 at least.

Comment: Import the database as a project in SSDT, fix things at your leisure (or with a mass search-replace), then produce a change script (to verify only the stuff that needs upgrading is in there). You still have to "amend each trigger manually" this way, but in a much more controlled fashion. (It's possible the SSDT project will flag even more things that were always broken and not noticed until now; this would be a good opportunity to fix those.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code is using the undocumented version of [RAISEERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that is no longer supported in 2012+

replace anything like this

```
RAISERROR 9999 'User already exists.'
```

to something like this

```
DECLARE @ERRMSG NVARCHAR(100) = 'User already exists.', @ErrorSeverity INT = 9999
RAISERROR (@ERRMSG,@ErrorSeverity,1 )
```